# Viewchild undefined with material angular matsidenav

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm using Material with angular, and I want to toggle the Sidenav from another component, using viewchild, but i get undefined when i try to get the mat-sidenav element. Heres mi code

**sidenav.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
       Sidenav content goes here!
    </mat-sidenav>

    <div class="sidenav-container">
        123
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSidenav} from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidemenu',
  templateUrl: './sidemenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidemenu.component.scss']
})
export class SidemenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openSideNav(){   
    console.log(this.sidenav)
    this.sidenav.open();
  }
}
```

And this is the component from where i try to toggle the sidenav

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidemenuComponent } from '../sidemenu/sidemenu.component';
@Component({
  providers:[SidemenuComponent],
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sm: SidemenuComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openSideNav(){ 
    this.sm.openSideNav()


    }
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <div class="navbar-brand">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/icons/logo_femsa_blanco.png"/>
    </div>
    <button class="buton-menu" mat-icon-button (click)="openSideNav()">
        <img class="img-fluid menu-icon" src="./assets/icons/icons8-menu-filled-50.png"/>
      </button>
    <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
    <div class="font-weight-light text-right user-name">
        Hola Mundo!
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Hope someone can help. I's starting with angular. Sorry for bad english

Comment: official sample : https://stackblitz.com/angular/moydvkykppea?file=app%2Fsidenav-open-close-example.html you have full api to toggle mat-toolbar

Comment: I use this as example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjvepjgxdaao?file=app%2Fsidenav-disable-close-example.ts but i donk know what i did wrong

Comment: i can't understand your issue, and your component relation, please provide stackblitz sample such as https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqimtm?file=app%2Fsidenav-disable-close-example.ts

Comment: I made this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmjtzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base on your sample, i have create Service to manage communication between component.

Goal is to have, from anywhere on your code, API to ask menu to open / close / toggle.

Functional step :

1/ From anywhere (button click, custom things), you want to make action on your side-nav. You call public function from your service, exemple : `this.menuService.open()`

2/ if needed, your service will next new menu state by Observable.

3/ Component who manage your sidenav will subscribe to any change on this state and do "open/close" if needed.

---

State is manage by Subject and internal service flag

```
export class MenuService {
    private menuIsOpen$ : Subject<boolean>;
    private menuIsOpen: boolean = false;
    constructor() { 
        this.menuIsOpen$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    }

    /**
    * If menu is open, let close it
    **/
    public open() {
            if(!this.menuIsOpen) {
                this.menuIsOpen = true;
                this.menuIsOpen$.next(false);
            }
    }
    /**
     * Both silence open and close is use by navbar output, to silence switch internal flag.
     **/
    public silenceOpen() {
        this.menuIsOpen = true;
    }
    public silenceClose() {
        this.menuIsOpen = false;
    }

    /**
    * If menu is close, let open it
    **/
    public close() {
            if(this.menuIsOpen) {
                this.menuIsOpen = false;
                this.menuIsOpen$.next(false);
            }
    }

    public toggle() {
        this.menuIsOpen = !this.menuIsOpen;
        this.menuIsOpen$.next(this.menuIsOpen);
    }

    public asObservable() 
    {
        return this.menuIsOpen$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

then your Component who embed sidenav :

```
export class SidemenuComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

    constructor(private menuService: MenuService) 
    {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        /**
        When you reveive order to open / close sidenav.
        **/
        this.menuService.asObservable().subscribe((isOpen: boolean) => {
                    if(isOpen) {
                        this.sidenav.close();
                    }
                    else{
                        this.sidenav.open();
                    }
            });
    }

    onOpenedChange() {
        this.menuService.silenceOpen();
    }
    onClosedChange() {
        this.menuService.silenceClose();
    }
}
```

Html side :

Sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2faa8z

Comment: Ta¡hank you so much.

Comment: my pleasure, i recommand you to always consider to create service when you need cross Component/module/directive communication and base all your mutable state as Observable.